# 2 ip, 2 document roots?

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, http

One CentOS box comes with 2 LAN cards, one is for intranet (192.168.30.5), one is for public access (210.102.1.50). How can I config `httpd.conf` such that traffics from each IP will access to a different document root? i.e.: traffic from intranet -> `/var/www/html/intranet/`, traffic from the web -> `/var/www/html/internet/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a virtual host ([Apache Virtual Host Documents](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)). A virtual host can do exactly what your describing (assuming your using apache httpd) - this information is put into your httpd.conf

An example, modified from their website:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.30.5>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/intranet
ServerName www.domain.tld
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 210.102.1.50>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/internet
ServerName www.domain.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

There are many more options, such as custom logs and such, please refer to the documentation.